# Azure client connect to rabbitmq

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-appservice, azure-container-registry

Thanks in advance.

In Azure. I created a container registry with marketplace image: RabbitMQ packaged by Bitnami.
Created an App Service from the container registry.
Add the WEBSITES_PORT: 15672 configuration.
I can open the RabbitMQ management from the App Service without problem.

But I can't connect the client to rabbitMQ I tried all ports, 5672 especially but it wont work.

Please help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If the necessary ports are not open on the rabbitmq ,you get this "**No route to host"** error

when the client tries to connect, make sure the ports are open, if not, open them like below:

```php
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5672 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5673 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 15672 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

This is for temporarily, try to set it on permanently in your iptables

```php
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Then restart:

```php
sudo service iptables restart
```

Or try to stop and restart your rabbit as given below

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-set-up-rabbitmq-cluster-azure-akshay-kunila

[RabbitMQ trigger for Azure Functions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)